# pivot multi column and mutil row

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my origin data:

```
ID New LikeNew Old  Warehouse
1  10  100     20   LA
1  12  130     40   CA
2  90  200     10   LA
2  103 230     30   CA
```

i want to get the following format:

```
ID LA_new LA_likeNew LA_Old CA_New CA_LikeNew CA_Old  
1  10     100        20     12     130        40
2  90     200        10     103    230        30
```

I can only pivot on each column but can not do on all 3 columns(New, LikeNew, Old) , so how can I do that?

Comment: Look at my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009465/multiple-row-values-to-same-row-and-different-columns/50011641#50011641.  << Essentially, you'll `UNPIVOT` then `PIVOT`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple row values to same row and different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009465/multiple-row-values-to-same-row-and-different-columns)

Comment: Do you always have the same columns or does the warehouse portion need to be dynamic?

Comment: And the OP has disappeared. Why bother asking a question on a forum if you are not interested in a solution and participating in the question??

Comment: @SeanLange: i was busy, the warehouse is dynamic

Comment: Do you have to have named columns for each warehouse? Could you instead have numbered columns? Warehouse1, new1,...Warehouse2, new2

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using conditional logic to create your fields and grouping:

```
select id,  
max(case when warehouse = 'LA' then new else null end) LA_New,
max(case when warehouse = 'LA' then likenew else null end) LA_likeNew,
max(case when warehouse = 'LA' then old else null end) LA_Old,
max(case when warehouse = 'CA' then new else null end) CA_New,
max(case when warehouse = 'CA' then likenew else null end) CA_likeNew,
max(case when warehouse = 'CA' then old else null end) CA_Old
from yourtable
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [WITH Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
       DECLARE @T AS TABLE
        (
          id INT ,
          New INT ,
          likeNew INT ,
          old INT ,
          Warehouse VARCHAR(50)
        )

       INSERT   INTO @T
                ( id, New, likeNew, old, Warehouse )
       VALUES   ( 1, 10, 100, 20, 'LA' ),
                ( 1, 12, 130, 40, 'CA' ),
                ( 2, 90, 200, 10, 'LA' ),
                ( 2, 103, 230, 30, 'CA' );
       WITH cte
              AS ( SELECT   *
                   FROM     @T
                   WHERE    Warehouse = 'LA'
                 ),
            cte1
              AS ( SELECT   *
                   FROM     @T
                   WHERE    Warehouse = 'CA'
                 )
        SELECT  a.id ,
                a.new [LA_New] ,
                a.likeNew [LA_LikeNew] ,
                a.Old [LA_Old] ,
                b.new [CA_New] ,
                b.likeNew [CA_LikeNew] ,
                b.Old [CA_Old]
        FROM    cte A
                JOIN cte1 B ON a.id = b.id
```

Result:

```
    id          LA_New      LA_LikeNew  LA_Old      CA_New      CA_LikeNew  CA_Old
    ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
    1           10          100         20          12          130         40
    2           90          200         10          103         230         30
```

Comment: You don't cte2 at all. Just execute the select statement.

Comment: thanks @SeanLange, applied the change you suggested.